# Stop user subscription after 200 users in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, limit, subscription

I wonder if there is any function or plugin to stop user subscription after 200 users? I can't find it out in Google or the WordPress forums. Hopefully there is a an function that shows a custom message or page after reaching 200.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: For this you need to create function, in which function check is user reaching 200. If user limit reached at 200 then user subscription page set as disable.

Answer (score 1):

You can login with your admin user in your backend when you see that there are 200 users registered ( /wp-admin ) and you can go to Settings > General and check the option "anyone can register."

I will continue investigating to find the solution.

Regards,

Eric.